# JSON and AngularJS (trying to figure out the ng-repeat part)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

So I have this on my JSON file:

```
[{
    "title": "Secondary Containment",
    "products": {
        "product": [
            {
                "id": "1001",
                "name": "one"
            },
            {
                "id": "1002",
                "name": "two"
            },
            {
                "id": "1003",
                "name": "three"
            }
        ]
    }
}, {
    "title": "Another Title",
    "products": {
        "product": [
            {
                "id": "1011",
                "name": "alpha"
            },
            {
                "id": "1012",
                "name": "beta"
            },
            {
                "id": "1013",
                "name": "gamma"
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

What would I include in my ng-repeat to repeat the id's of the products in a list?

I have ng-repeat="category in categories" in my outer container which is repeating the different titles {{category.title}} but it's not repeating the inner array and nothing shows up when i try outputting {{category.products.product.id}}

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code where you repeat the categories? That would help a lot.

Comment: use multiple ng-repeats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need nested `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <div ng-repeat="product in category.products.product">
        {{product.id}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your html should be

```
<div data-ng-repeat="category in categories">
 <div data-ng-repeat="product in category.products.product">
   {{product.id}} 
 </div>
</div>
```

You can do as nikhil said. But you need nested `ng-repeat`. But I personally suggest to use `data-ng-repeat` instead `ng-repeat`. The only main reason to use `data-ng-*` **is** `The data-ng-* allows the HTML to be validated through validators that do not understand Angular`

Comment: category.products is an object - your code will not work.

Comment: is there a specific reason to use data-ng-repeat instead of ng-repeat?

Comment: Yes, there is. in many browsers `ng-repeat` directive throws an error

Comment: @Vineet - I would like to differ on that. I have a live project supporting all major browsers and have no issue in using ng-repeat.